# Nuxt firebase write doc after createUserWithEmailAndPassword fail

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

The idea of register form is

1. add user email and password to firebase auth, this is successful, then
2. add new document using their `uid` as document id and insert street field and value; to `profile` collection, failed without error.

The user and email are added to the auth users in firebase console, but the document writing still unsuccessfull with no error on the console either.

Been scratching my head for awhile.

Here's my code

```
<template>
    <v-form @submit.prevent="createUser">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="register.email"
            label="Email"
            required
        />
        <v-text-field
            v-model="register.password"
            label="Password"
            required
        />
        <v-text-field
            v-model="register.street"
            required
            label="Street"
        />
        <v-btn
            type="submit"
        >
            Register
        </v-btn>
    </v-form>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { auth, db } from '~/plugins/firebase.js'

export default Vue.extend({
  data () {
    return {
      register: {}
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    async createUser () {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        this.register.email,
        this.register.password
      ).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.code)
        console.log(error.message)
      })

      onAuthStateChanged(
        auth,
        (user) => {
          if (user) {
            const ref = doc(db, 'profile', user.uid)
            const document = {
              street: this.register.street
            }
            try {
              setDoc(ref, document)
            } catch (e) {
              alert('Error!')
              console.error(e.code)
              console.error(e.message)
            }
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

firestore rule with no restriction

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following:

```
async createUser () {
  await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    auth,
    this.register.email,
    this.register.password
  )
  .then((user) => {
      this.writeToFirestore(user)
  })
 .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.code)
    console.log(error.message)
  })
},

async writeToFirestore(user) {
  if (user) {
    const ref = doc(db, 'profile', user.id)
    const document = {
      street: this.register.street
    }
    try {
      setDoc(ref, document)
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Error!')
      console.error(e.code)
      console.error(e.message)
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Little modification on my side I put `this.writeToFirestore(user)` inside `onAuthStateChanged` , just to make sure writing happens after user registered in the backend.